# How to block a developer certificate

Tags: macos, security, malware

I accidentally installed Mac Cleanup Pro when I was going to upgrade Flash for a web site. I've used 'Little Snitch' to block the sites it connects to. The malware is all signed by a Developer ID 'vijay ameta (3Q3PBWQ48N)' which is issued by Apple Inc.

Is there a way to block that certificate?
(is there a way to get Apple to withdraw the certificate?)

Comment: Do you believe this software has violated any terms Apple has made a requirement for developers? That would make this an easier task to accomplish overall.

Comment: Yes because it pretends to be a flash upgrade and then installs other software including changing browser home page setting etc.

Comment: Yes - that seems awful. Please report and potentially let others know. Not sure you want to name / shame them here so that’s your call if you’re certain it’s bad or you want to get others assessment and be more cautious about what happens. It’s not clear if that was the payload dropped by malware or that is the malware for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure you can block it other than uninstalling it and whatever you did to install it (other installer, other app, ???)

To get Apple’s attention, unless they sold that app on the App Store or you were sure you can locate an app that’s signed from the Mac App Store or iOS App Store from the same developer, I’d start with Apple Support to report potential loss of that developer’s Apple ID.

- https://getsupport.apple.com/

If you assume no developer would sign code that does bad things, you can also assume that somehow they lost their keys and someone is abusing their keys to spread bad software. If it turns out they are the bad person, you’re not making the assumption of anything other than their keys were used for something they may or may not have approved.